# MKAnnotation undeclared

Tags: xcode, mkannotation

I have an error with this code:

```
MKAnnotation *ann = [MKAnnotation alloc];
```

Error:

```
MKAnnotation undeclared
```

I already import the following:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MKAnnotation` is not a class - it is a [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1) defining an interface to objects that can act as annotations on map - so any object that conforms to that protocol (i.e. implements all required methods) can be used in its place.